# Correctly formatted multidimensional array from php file not parsing in jquery ajax function

Tags: php, jquery, arrays

I am attempting to create an online Bible for a ministry site I am working on. It allows the user to select a book of the Bible, which, in turn, populates the chapters div using jQuery, upon which when a chapter is clicked, it is **supposed** to populate the actual chapter using jQuery.

The book click works fine and populates the related chapters, but the chapter click does nothing.

[image: pic of the rendered bible]

**Here is the Html**

```
/* showBibleWrap
    ------------------------------------------------------ */
    echo '<div class="showBibleWrap">';

        # bible books
        echo '<div class="bibleBooks">'; 
            echo file_get_contents($level.'core/bible/data/books-of-the-bible.dat');
        echo '</div>';

        # bible chapters
        echo '<div class="bibleChapters"></div>';

        # show bible results
        echo '<div class="bibleResults"></div>';

    echo '</div>';
```

**The Html included on books-of-the-bible.dat**

```
<div class="gChapters" data-theBook="Genesis" data-chapterCt="50">Genesis</div>
<div class="gChapters" data-theBook="Exodus" data-chapterCt="40">Exodus</div>...
```

On the click of `.gChapters` uses jQuery to appends the chapters to the DOM based on the `data-chapterCt="50"` attribute.

**jQuery - this works fine**

```
$(".gChapters").click(function(){
    var whichBook = $(this).attr("data-theBook");
    var ct = $(this).attr("data-chapterCt");

    $('.bibleChapters').html('');

    for (i = 0; i < ct; i++) {
        var ii = i + 1;
        $('.bibleChapters').append('<div class="chapters" data-book="'+whichBook+'" data-chapter="'+ii+'">'+ii);
    }

});
```

The script is **supposed** to append the related chapter to `.bibleResults` on the click of `.chapters` using jQuery Ajax **but this does not work**.

**The jQuery**

```
$(".chapters").click(function(){
    var whichBook = $(this).attr("data-book");
    var chapter = $(this).attr("data-chapter");
    $('.bibleResults').html('');

    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:siteURL + 'core/bible/parse-verses.php',
        data: {whichBook:whichBook, chapter:chapter} ,
        success: function (JSONObject) {

            $.each(JSONObject, function(k,item){                
            $('.bibleResults').append('<p class="verseWrap"><b>['+item.book_name+' '+item.chapter_id+':'+item.this_verse_id+']</b>&nbsp;'+item.verse);  
            });     
        }
    });
});
```

**The parse-verses.php file**

```
$level = '../../';  
    include($level.'inc/ini.php');

    $whichBook = $_POST['whichBook'];
    $chapter = $_POST['chapter'];

    $selectqup = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM  verses_of_bible WHERE book_name=:THENAME AND chapter_id=:CHAP");
    $selectqup->bindValue(':THENAME',$whichBook,PDO::PARAM_INT); 
    $selectqup->bindValue(':CHAP',$chapter,PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $selectqup->execute();

    $verses = array();

    while($row = $selectqup->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){$verses[] = $row;}

    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($verses);
```

I have tested the `json_encode($verses);` and it renders a correct json multidimensional array.

**json array**

```
[{"verse_id":"7129","testament":"Old","book_id":"8","book_name":"Ruth","chapter_id":"1","this_verse_id":"1","verse":" Now it came to pass in the days when the judges ruled, that there was a famine in the land. And a certain man of Beth-lehem-judah went to sojourn in the country of Moab, he, and his wife, and his two sons."},{"verse_id":"7130","testament":"Old","book_id":"8","book_name":"Ruth","chapter_id":"1","this_verse_id":"2","verse":" And the name of the man [was] Elimelech, and the name of his wife Naomi, and the name of his two sons Mahlon and Chilion, Ephrathites of Beth-lehem-judah. And they came into the country of Moab, and continued there."},...
```

I have been on this for two days... I have researched to the point of confusion... whatever you can do to assist is much appreciated.

Comment: Looks to me like the return is proper json and is an array of objects. OK.  I suspect you need to do some sort of JSON.parse on the 'JSONObject' value when you receive it in your success function.

Comment: Thanks Yishmeray for responding... I am not quite sure how to parse the JSON any other way... could you expound... thanks

Comment: Of course, @petebolduc - Let me get a bit of a code snippet for you -- try {
retVal = JSON.parse(JSONObject); } catch (e) { /* parse failed */ } -- _now_ you have a nice array of objects in retVal.

Comment: Yishmery I tried to implement your code in a couple of different ways to no avail... was wondering if you could show an example of its use in my function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK - trying to preserve as much as possible of your code.

```js
$(".chapters").click(function(){
  var whichBook = $(this).attr("data-book");
  var chapter = $(this).attr("data-chapter");
  $('.bibleResults').html('');

  $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:siteURL + 'core/bible/parse-verses.php',
    data: {whichBook:whichBook, chapter:chapter} ,
    success: function (JSONObject) {
      try { const retVal = JSON.parse(JSONObject); } catch (e) { /* parse failed */ }
      console.log(`Parsed! Length of object = ${Object.keys(retVal).length}`); //
      // 
      retVal.forEach( function(item) {
        $('.bibleResults').append(`<p class="verseWrap"><b>${item.book_name}${item.chapter_id}:${item.this_verse_id}]</b>&nbsp;${item.verse}`);        
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your time Yishmeray... I am sure your code is working fine... I found out the verses being returned have quotations and square brackets in them... I ran them through htmlentities() and did a str_replace() for the brackets but the script still does not work... I appreciate your time